# TestDisk "You have to reboot for the change to take efferct"

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, live-usb, data-recovery

I accidentally delete my entire disk. Now I am using TestDisk to recover the **Harddisk**. `The problem is it is asking for reboot and only after if will start recovering and unfortunately I am running ubuntu from a live disk`. Every time I reboot if start a fresh copy of Ubuntu. Please, I am in a big trouble and I really don't want to lose the files. Help Please.

Comment: Testdisk should only ask to reboot in case you write a brand new partition table. Which you can do without problems, then boot again and try to access the partitions it wrote previously.

Comment: I don't understand though - shouldn't it read the partition table when you try to mount it after writing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have used [**MiniTool Partition Wizard Bootable Edition**](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-wizard-bootable-cd.html). I downloaded the iso, and it worked for me . Now I have data back .. Oh.. I am safe at last.